# GORM / Hibernate: Criteria joining joining (cast) to property's child

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm, criteria

I have this structure:

```groovy
class A {
  static belongsTo = [b: B]
}

class C extends B {
  String identifier
}
```

I'm trying to create a criteria that sorts by a property of C:

```groovy
A.createCriteria(max: max, offset: offset).list {
  createAlias(b, c) // This is what I don't know how to do it or how to cast it
  order("c.identifier", "desc")
}
```

I don't know if there is a way to cast or specify the class of the child.

Comment: createAlias is for creating shortcut for the long table names not for casting

Answer (score 0):

According to the OO principles, you should not access a B child property from A.

Anyway, you can try this:

```
class B {
  A a
}
```

And the hql query:

```
C.executeQuery("select a from C as c inner join c.a as a order by c.identifier")
```